# multiple checkbox filtering php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am filtering the results from the database using checkboxes and it works fine with one checkbox however when I check multiple checkboxes it returns the rows only for the first checkbox. How can I have it to filter the results with multiple checkboxes?

Here are the checkboxes

```
 <form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="football" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['football'])?' checked':'')?>/> Football<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="basketball" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['basketball'])?' checked':'')?>/> Basketball<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="volleyball" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['volleyball'])?' checked':'')?>/> Volley Ball<br>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function(){
     $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the select query.. the third `else if` statement returns only the first checkbox value which is basketball

```
if (isset($_POST["football"])){
  $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM balls where type LIKE '%foot%' ORDER BY id desc", $options);
 }

else if (isset($_POST["basketball"])){
  $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM balls where type LIKE '%bask%'   ORDER BY id desc", $options);
 }

else if (isset($_POST["volleyball"])){
  $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM balls where type LIKE '%vol%'  ORDER BY id desc", $options);
 }

else if (isset($_POST["basketball"]) && isset($_POST["football"]) && isset($_POST["volleyball"])){
  $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM balls where type LIKE '%bask%' or type LIKE '%foot%' or type LIKE '%vol%' ORDER BY id desc", $options);
 }

else { $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM balls ORDER BY id desc', $options);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If football is set your page won't call any of the other functions. You could fix it by putting the `if (isset($_POST["basketball"]) && isset($_POST["football"]) && isset($_POST["volleyball"])){` as the first argument instead of the third, but this method doesn't handle cases where only two of the three are selected.

**EDIT 1:**
A more appropriate method would be to have the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["basketball"]) {
  $arguments[] = "type LIKE '%bask%'";
}
if (isset($_POST["football"]) {
  $arguments[] = "type LIKE '%foot%'";
}
if (isset($_POST["volleyball"]) {
  $arguments[] = "type LIKE '%vol%'";
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
  $str = implode(' or ',$arguments);

  $qry = "SELECT * FROM balls where " . $str . " ORDER BY id desc";

  $paginate = new pagination($page, $qry, $options);
} else {
  //Whatever happens when there's none checked.
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Let me explain what's going on here. First we check each post variable to see if its set. If it is, we add a value to the `$arguments` array with the `type LIKE '%search term%'` argument.

Then once we've checked all of our arguments, we implode them together and delimit by " or ". We then plug this argument string into our query and run a single pagination with exactly what we need. No more, no less.

Comment: yep that is also a prob. what would be better approach for handling such selection?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you could deal with multiple scenarios.

Comment: this gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$paginate'`

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Add a semicolon after the `$qry = "SELECT * FROM balls where " . $str . " ORDER BY id desc"`
I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: also does this return all the rows from the table if none of the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: Right, I've changed it so you can execute whatever code you want if none are checked.

Comment: I would really love it if this works but when I check the boxes it returns nothing

Comment: Try doing an `echo $qry;` after the $qry is set and post what it returns.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM balls where type LIKE '%foot%' ORDER BY id desc` This is what it returns when I do echo.

Comment: That is exactly what you had originally so without seeing more code I can't determine what's not working.

Comment: sorry I had no record with that value. Thanks a lot it works perfect.

Comment: $qry = "SELECT * FROM balls where $str ORDER BY id desc"; dont use " . $str . " with ""
ok with ''

Answer (score 0):

You use a sequence of `else if` blocks. Therefore, only one will be evaluated.

Change this and you will be fine.